# Angular 2+ ngIf Not Stopping Child Component From Building

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a parent component that calls in child component.  I want an ngIf check to show/build or hide/don't build child component... no matter what the component is built even when not displayed (not in dom).  Is there another way to stop this from happening?

Parent HTML Template:

```
<div>
  <child-comp *ngIf="1 == 0"></child-comp>
</div>
```

I am thinking that ngIf won't get me where I want to be.

Comment: I didn't get your question, the above code doesn't add your component to dom, it will show as comments if you take a loot at source

Comment: @RezaRahmati When I run the above the ts file for the child-comp gets ran still - even though the ngif stops it from being produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `ngIf` check in the outer `div` around your `child-comp`

Comment: Or remove the enclosing `<div>` and just have the `child-comp>`

Comment: Well that was stupid lol..  I went with <ng-container to avoid the extra div.

Comment: @NicholasK Not following what you mean just have the child-comp>?

Comment: Yes (Along with the check `ngIf`). Any reason why there is a surrounding `div`?

Comment: @NicholasK That is what I did originally.  By doing that the child component's ts file would still fire/be built.  When I surround it - it stops it from being built.  I am assuming Angular see the child-comp tags starts the build and then see the ng-if maybe and stops it from the dom only. Vs. sees the div or ng-container in this case > sees the ngif on it and stops there - therefore not reaching the child-comp.